# Create WPF TextBox that accepts only numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I would like to create a TextBox that only accepts numeric values, in a specific range.
What is the best way to implement such TextBox?

I thought about deriving TextBox and to override the validation and coercion of the TextProperty. However, I am not sure how to do this, and I understand that deriving WPF control is generally not recommended.

---

**Edit:**
What I needed was a very basic textbox that filters out all key presses which are not digits.
The easiest way to achieve it is to handle the TextBox.PreviewTextInput event:

```
private void textBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    int result;
    if (!validateStringAsNumber(e.Text,out result,false))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

(validateStringAsNumber is my function that primarily use Int.TryParse)

Some of the suggested solutions are probably better, but for the simple functionality I needed this solution is the easiest and quickest to implement while sufficient for my needs.

Comment: Check my question on this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511/numeric-data-entry-in-wpf

Comment: Or maybe something like this :
private void txtNumeric_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Text.Any(c=>!char.IsDigit(c)))
    e.Handled = true;
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most implementations I have seen so far are using the [PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) event to implement the correct mask behavior. [This one](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/10/28/masked-textbox/) inherits from TextBox and [this one](http://wekempf.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D18C3EC06EA971CF!508.entry) uses attached properties. Both use .Net's [MaskedTextProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.maskedtextprovider.aspx) to provide the correct mask behaviour, but if you just want a simple 'numbers only' textbox you don't need this class.

Answer (score 6):

```
private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    int iValue = -1;

    if (Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out iValue) == false)
    {
         TextChange textChange = e.Changes.ElementAt<TextChange>(0);
         int iAddedLength = textChange.AddedLength;
         int iOffset = textChange.Offset;

         textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove(iOffset, iAddedLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use the code above I retrieve error message: "Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Windows.Controls.TextChange>' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt' and no extension method 'ElementAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Windows.Controls.TextChange>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) NewProduct.xaml.cs 104 51 MediaStore"
What reference is missing?

Comment: @Legato probably different .net framework

Answer (score 4):

In my humble opinion, the best way to fulfill this requirement is using only `OnTextChanged` event because it can handle the digit from keystroke and also be able to handle Copy+Paste from clipboard too. I hope that my VB code shown below can throw some light on this.

```vb
Private Sub NumericBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.TextChanged
  Dim Buffer As New StringBuilder
  Dim Index As Integer = Me.SelectionStart
  For Each C In Me.Text
    If Char.IsDigit(C) Then
      Buffer.Append(C)
    ElseIf Me.SelectionStart > Buffer.Length Then
      Index -= 1
    End If
  Next
  Me.Text = Buffer.ToString
  Me.SelectionStart = Index
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The overall best why is to use the override method `OnKeyPressed` for the textbox like. Here is the code for the override using the static Char Method `IsDigit`.

```
if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) e.Handled = true;
```

That is all you really need to do.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it won't allow you to use the decimal point (.)

Comment: `TextBox` only has `KeyDown` and `PreviewKeyDown` events which send parameter as `KeyEventArgs` . and this doesn't contain `KeyChar` property only `Key` property which returns one from `Keys` enum

Comment: Also, what if someone wanted to paste a number from the clipboard?

Answer (score -1):

This would be my preferred approach:

```
private void yearTxt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Key)
  {
    case Key.D0:
    case Key.D1:
    case Key.D2:
    case Key.D3:
    case Key.D4:
    case Key.D5:
    case Key.D6:
    case Key.D7:
    case Key.D8:
    case Key.D9:
    case Key.NumLock:
    case Key.NumPad0:
    case Key.NumPad1:
    case Key.NumPad2:
    case Key.NumPad3:
    case Key.NumPad4:
    case Key.NumPad5:
    case Key.NumPad6:
    case Key.NumPad7:
    case Key.NumPad8:
    case Key.NumPad9:
    case Key.Back:
      break;
    default:
      e.Handled = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use numeric text boxes often and don't want to repeat the code a lot, you can do this:
         
1. Make a method by renaming Bryuns code to 'numericTextBox' or something similar.
          
2. Call the method in 'PreviewKeyDown' events like this:
        
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   numericTextBox(sender, e);
}

Comment: This does not handle pasted text or users modifying numeric keys and typing chars like $%^. Also the user cannot use the arrow keys to move the caret.