# How to check inputed contains text

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create WPF TextBox that accepts only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226128/create-wpf-textbox-that-accepts-only-numbers)

How i can check if inputed value in textbox contains text? I want to user input only numbers
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using integers then:

```
int value = 0;
if(!Int32.TryParse(strInput, out value))
{
    // Validation failed - show error or feedback to user
}
else
{
    // Validation successful
}
```

For doubles, replace `Int32.TryParse` with `Double.TryParse` etc.

There is probably some fancy WPF way to do this as well (as indicated by V4Vendetta's comment).

Comment: +1 for TryParse rather than Parse - you don't want to be throwing exceptions if you're expecting things not to parse correctly sometimes.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you help me again? I want to allow numbers and . (dot) how i can do that?

Comment: Well, the example I posted is for Integers. You could try using `Double.TryParse` instead of `Int32.TryParse` - a 'double' allows you to have decimal places, so it will allow numbers like `5.5` as well as just `5`. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You could you a regular expression to check for `@"[^\d]"` if true there are non numbers

Alternatively `@"^\d+$"` will match ints and `@"\d+(\.\d+)?$"` will match decimals

Alternatively you could use a maskedtextbox control, either by embeding the winforms control using a host control or using something like Infragistics editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only number check if you can parse it. If you want `int` use `int.Parse()`