# Prevent user from typing certain char in TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, mvvm-light

I am using WPF, MVVM-Light.
In my UI I have a textbox, and I want to prevent the user from typing certain characters in the textbox.
I know if we use code-behind I could handle the key down keyPress events, can I achieve it through MVVM?
Can we use some behaviors or some interactivity triggers?

Answer (score 1):

Using code-behind is perfectly OK with MVVM providing the code-behind is related to your View only.

So if you have some view-specific logic that says *"User can only type numbers in this box"*, then it's perfectly OK to write a `KeyPress` event for the `TextBox` that only allows numeric keys to be processed. You could even throw this into a `UserControl` so it can be reusable.

However if your allowed character logic is based on application logic, such as *"User can only use the characters defined in the app.config file for this string value"*, then you'd be better off validating that in the ViewModel.

Also note that restriction is different from validation.

If you want to *validate* a user's entry, then I would do so using `IDataErrorInfo` from the ViewModel layer, and possibly a binding with a mode of `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` so the validation is checked after every key press.

If you want to *restrict* what characters can be typed into a `TextBox`, then I would probably do that from the View layer in the code behind, as that is a functionality of the View.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to filter input the MVVM way, I would suggest either using a custom control (such as a masked `TextBox` control) or a Behavior.

I was recently looking for a good masked `TextBox` and there is a free one out there from Xceed which you can find [here](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox).  I can't speak to this one, as I haven't used it, but I've been happy with other Xceed components I've used in the past.

However I didn't want to go third party and include a bunch of controls I didn't need, so I ended up creating a behavior that simply attaches to the `TextBox` and filters the input based on a FilterType.  The behavior is pretty easy to create, and you simply use the `PreviewTextInput` event to filter out characters that you don't want.

[This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226128/create-wpf-textbox-that-accepts-only-numbers) has a number of suggestions and links to how to filter/mask the input and if you're not familiar with creating Attached Behaviors, [this example](http://digitaltapestry.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/the-first-rule-of-wpf/) shows how to create an Attached Behavior for a Masked Text Box.