# Catch format exception in a WPF datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid in which I need to add some columns using code. One of those columns need to contain only double values (no text and no empty string). The binding is perform using code on a Double property so this seems to work fine when the value is valid.

When the user does enter a invalid value, the column turns red. However, if I check the content of the column, it's still the old value and I can see that the rowChanged event did not occur.

If I don't do anything, I notice in the output that a system.formatexception was thrown and if I add a validationrule, it disappears and I can return a validationResult to false, but I have no idea what to do with it after...

So my question is this : Can I catch the FormatException in the ouput and how ?

OR

What can I do to "catch" my validation rule failure ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would prefer to *avoid* the error, rather than to *handle* it. You could do that by creating a really simple numeric only `TextBox`. That way, the user won't be able to input invalid values. You only need to handle a couple of events to achieve the desired result, so this is a perfect candidate for an `AttachedProperty`. You can find out how to do this if you take a look at the [Create WPF TextBox that accepts only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226128/create-wpf-textbox-that-accepts-only-numbers) post.

Answer (score 0):

when binding try to set value back to your Source Property and when there is type mismatch exception is thrown . For this you can set **FallBackValue in binding** and if you dont want it to turn red then set **ValidatesOnExceptions=false** in Binding