# WPF Text Box Validation on numeric value

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

if have a text box in xaml. i want only numeric values can be write in textbox to validate on button. how can i do it ?

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtLevel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numeric Data Entry in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511/numeric-data-entry-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a class to host all of the additions to textbox that you want to make like below, the bit that stops you putting numbers is in the event handler for PreviewTextInput, if it's not numeric I just say the event is handled and the textbox never gets the value.

```
public class TextBoxHelpers : DependencyObject
{

    public static bool GetIsNumeric(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsNumericProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsNumeric(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsNumericProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsNumeric.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
           public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNumericProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsNumeric", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxHelpers), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
            {
                TextBox targetTextbox = s as TextBox;
                if (targetTextbox != null)
                {
                    if ((bool)e.OldValue && !((bool)e.NewValue))
                    {
                        targetTextbox.PreviewTextInput -= targetTextbox_PreviewTextInput;

                    }
                    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                    {
                        targetTextbox.PreviewTextInput += targetTextbox_PreviewTextInput;
                        targetTextbox.PreviewKeyDown += targetTextbox_PreviewKeyDown;
                    }
                }
            })));

    static void targetTextbox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space;
    }

    static void targetTextbox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Char newChar = e.Text.ToString()[0];
        e.Handled = !Char.IsNumber(newChar);
    }
}
```

To use the helper class with attached property in XAML you need to point a namespace to it then use it like this.

```
<TextBox local:TextBoxHelpers.IsNumeric="True" />
```

Comment: what if the value enter is 3  5, i.e white space between numeric values. i want only numeric value > 0 with no white space. It actually works fine for non numeric characters but not for white space

Comment: Just add the check for the space too e.Handled = !Char.IsNumber(e.Text.ToString()[0]) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (e.Text.ToString()[0]);

Comment: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace is not a found within string class  !!

Comment: oops, don't know what version of .net that came in, you can just do the check for null then do a check for " "

Comment: Still not working. when i press space bar to enter white space in textbox, targetTextbox_PreviewTextInput event is not firing instead

Comment: Well I didn't know that! I've updated again, you can use key down to block the spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numericUppDown` instead of `textbox` so as to have only numeric input. That is the way to do it.

Comment: I am using .net 3.5 Framework, numericUpDown control is not available !!

Answer (score 0):

Use wpf behavior control. Example
http://wpfbehaviorlibrary.codeplex.com/