# MaskedTextBox taking only integer

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using MaskedTextBox.I want my textbox to take only digits upto 7 numerics.It should not take any special character like ,.@#,so on....I tried with "ddddddd" as mask but it allows decimal.So t works for decimal only.also tried with 000000

can anybody suggest for correct Mask.

```
:MaskedTextBox x:Name="TxtTutionFees"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Width="78"
                                       Height="23"
                                       Margin="142,40,0,0"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       AllowSign="False"
                                       DecimalPrecision="2"
                                       GroupNumerals="True"
                                       InputMask="ddddddd"
                                       IsEnabled="False"
                                       PromptChar=" "
                                       TextAlignment="Right"
                                       GotFocus ="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MaskedTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home) from [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

If you will use this control your solution is following:

```
 <xceed:MaskedTextBox x:Name="_maskedTextBox"
                             Mask="0000000"
                             ValueDataType="{x:Type s:Int32}" />
```

Where `xceed` and `s` are following namespaces:

```
xmlns:xceed="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: @user2500796 Yes, you can. Here is link to .net 3.5: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/downloads/get/679522

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an attached dependency property as in the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251506/wpf-text-box-validation-on-numeric-value/13255076#13255076). You can use this technique to filter out any characters that you don't want.