# WPF numeric format

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this XAML for acolumn into DataGrid

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="% Deduccion Anticipo">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumPorcentajeAnticipo, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:00.}%}" Visibility="{Binding Merlin_ConceptosFacturacion.BitOtrosItms_Anticipos,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding NumPorcentajeAnticipo, Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat={}{0:00.}%}" Visibility="{Binding Merlin_ConceptosFacturacion.BitOtrosItms_Anticipos,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The Stringformat applys as i expect, but muy problem is the user can fill it with any char alpha, number symbol, how can i do to prevent it, it is posible set an inputmask ?

I'm was trying with another StringFormats but any one of them work as I expect.

UPDATE: The column is currently binded to a Numeric property of my view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research found this on another question:

**Numeric Data Entry in WPF** And [@Brian Hinchey answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511/numeric-data-entry-in-wpf) match with some of my needs.

Just add by myself some Culture validations for **decimal numbers** plus some editing and validation tools. Hope this help somebody else.

To use it:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <controls:NumericTextBox DecimalPlaces="2" DecimalSeparator="."/>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

If no decimal places or separator are provided, it take `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` parms

Here is the final code:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    #region Formato
    private string previousText = "";
    private bool ApplyingFormat = false;
    private CultureInfo _CI = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID,true);
    public CultureInfo CI
    {
        get { return _CI; }
        set { _CI = value; }
    }

    private int _DecimalPlaces = 0;
    /// <summary>
    /// Numero de plazas decimales 
    /// </summary>
    public int DecimalPlaces
    {
        get { return _DecimalPlaces; }
        set { _DecimalPlaces = value; _CI.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = value; }
    }
    public Decimal DecimalValue = 0;

    private string _DecimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    public string DecimalSeparator
    {
        get { return _DecimalSeparator; }
        set { _DecimalSeparator = value; _CI.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = _DecimalSeparator; }
    }

    //public string DecimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    #endregion 


    public NumericTextBox()
    {
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this, OnPaste);
    }

    private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs dataObjectPastingEventArgs)
    {
        var isText = dataObjectPastingEventArgs.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.DataFormats.Text, true);
        if (isText)
        {
            var text = dataObjectPastingEventArgs.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
            if (IsTextValid(text))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        dataObjectPastingEventArgs.CancelCommand();
    }

    private bool IsTextValid(string enteredText)
    {
        //  If keyboard insert key is in toggled mode, and the actual insert point is Decimalseparator, we must avoid to overwrite it
        if (SelectionStart == this.Text.IndexOf(DecimalSeparator)
            & System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.GetKeyStates(System.Windows.Input.Key.Insert) == System.Windows.Input.KeyStates.Toggled)
        {
            SelectionStart += 1;
        }

        if (!enteredText.All(c => Char.IsNumber(c) || c == DecimalSeparator.ToCharArray()[0] || c == '-'))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //We only validation against unselected text since the selected text will be replaced by the entered text
        var unselectedText = this.Text.Remove(SelectionStart, SelectionLength);
        if ( enteredText == DecimalSeparator && unselectedText.Contains(DecimalSeparator))
        {
            //  Before return false, must move cursor beside Decimal separator
            SelectionStart = this.Text.IndexOf(DecimalSeparator) + 1;
            return false;
        }

        if (enteredText == "-" && unselectedText.Length > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private bool ApplyFormat(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ApplyingFormat)
        {
            ApplyingFormat = true;
            int SelectionStartActual = SelectionStart;
            string FinallText = this.Text;
            if (!FinallText.Contains(DecimalSeparator) & DecimalPlaces > 0)
            {
                FinallText = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", this.Text, DecimalSeparator, new string('0', DecimalPlaces));
            }
            bool state = Decimal.TryParse(FinallText, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign, _CI, out DecimalValue);
            DecimalValue = Math.Round(DecimalValue, DecimalPlaces);
            if (DecimalValue == 0)
            {
                FinallText = "";
            }
            else
            {
                if (FinallText != DecimalValue.ToString(_CI))
                {
                    FinallText = DecimalValue.ToString(_CI);
                }
            }
            if (FinallText != this.Text)
            {
                this.Text = FinallText;
                SelectionStart = SelectionStartActual;
            }

            previousText = this.Text;

            ApplyingFormat = false;
            return state;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !ApplyFormat(e);
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !IsTextValid(e.Text);
        base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx) event of a `TextBox` to intercept and filter out invalid values. You could even create your own derived `TextBox` and override `OnKeyDown` for a better encapsulated solution.

Answer (score 0):

None of the built-in controls have the ability to specify an input mask.  But, there are masked input controls out there on the internet for WPF.  We are using the Telerik Rad Controls for WPF package and it has such a control.  I use it in my application and it works very well.

Comment: There's really no need to *buy* a third-party control, it's fairly trivial to achieve what the OP wants by intercepting keypresses - no whether or not it's a good idea is a separate question

Comment: Tks for your answer, due to it is a very common thing I'm was expecting native WPF has this function.

Comment: @MattBurland:  True.  However, build it yourself means debug it yourself.  A third-party control will have been tested & debugged already.  Though that doesn't mean all of the bugs have been removed, either.  JuanPabloGomez: I don't believe masked input controls are available in WinForms, either.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your requirement by using following methods.

1. Put the masked textbox in CellEditingTemplate and set the  mask in that masked textbox.
2. Create the custom render based on your requirement and bind to the CellEditingTemplate.